# Using Dependency Injection from Azure Key Vault to grab a connection string for AddDbContextFactory

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, dbcontext, ihostedservice

I'm trying to set up the service registrations for my ihostedservice app and would like to pull in a connection string that is located in the key vault. What I have is something like this:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(app =>
    {
        app.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<SecretClient>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            // Set up Key Vault
        });
        services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(opt =>
        {
            var sp = service.BuildServiceProvider();
            var secretClient = sp.GetRequiredService<SecretClient>();
            var serviceNames = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<ServiceNames>>();
            var secretName = serviceNames.CurrentValue.Secret;
            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName);
            opt.UseSqlServer(secret.Value);
        }; 
     })
     .Build();
```

While perusing online, I found something that mentions that I should bare in mind the building of a service provider. Would there be a better way about registering a dbContextFactory? What would be best practices in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time if I find myself trying to use `GetRequiredService` as part of `ConfigureServices` there's a better way to do things. Generally you don't want to call DI services while you're setting up DI.

I would recommend getting the value from KeyVault as part of your deployment and reference the value there as an [application setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings). See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) for details on how to do so.

Comment: Just for clarification, this is going to be containerized into a kubernetes cluster. I am grabing the key vault settings from the appsettings json via the sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<ServiceNames>>(), I just did not add that into my example. I do use a hostContext.Configuration.GetSection to access the configuration from ConfigureServices. Would you have an example of adding a DbContextFactory outside of service configuration?